# How to select default drop-down option based on falsy value in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular2-template

In the following template, the "Select Military Status" option will be the selected option when the underlying `model.militaryStatus` property is `null`.

```html
<select [(ngModel)]="model.militaryStatus">
  <option [ngValue]="null">Select Military Status</option>
  <option *ngFor="let status of militaryStatuses" [value]="status.id">{{ status.description }}</option>
</select>
```

The problem is that in order for the "Select Military Status" option to be selected, the `ngModel`-bound field needs to be *exactly* `null` — not `undefined`, not a blank string, but `null`. If they aren't exactly equal, you will get something like this, where there is no selected option:

[image: Select list with no selected option]

Is there a way to display a given `option` when the underlying component property has *any* falsy value? This way, whether an API returns `0`, `undefined`, `null`, or a blank string (all common use cases depending on the scenario), the default option will be displayed without the broken user experience of a blank drop-down?

EDIT: [Here's a stackblitz sandbox showing an example of this issue](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-playground-qdmubj)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adapt the first option to the current value of `model.militaryStatus`:

- If `model.militaryStatus` is falsy, the value of the first option is `model.militaryStatus`
- If `model.militaryStatus` is truthy, the value of the first option is `null`

```
<select [(ngModel)]="model.militaryStatus">
  <option [ngValue]="!model.militaryStatus ? model.militaryStatus : null">Select Military Status</option>
  <option *ngFor="let status of militaryStatuses" [value]="status.id">{{ status.description }}</option>
</select>
```

See [**this stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yunih6) for a demo.

Answer (score 0):

For a template driven form, I did this and got default selection.

Assign `model.militaryStatus=null` in ts.

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hng38a?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: While this does work, I'm trying to avoid having to do this to "normalize" API responses that might be returning a blank string instead of a `null`. Having to manually convert falsy values to `null`s using something like `if (!!model.militaryStatus) { model.militaryStatus = null; }` just feels like it shouldn't be necessary.

Ideally, the API responses should be uniformly returning `null`s when appropriate, but modifying an API isn't always an option.

Comment: @JacobStamm will you get default value from API or this value will store in the client side?

Comment: In my case, from the API, but the source of the data shouldn't matter

Comment: @JacobStamm If default value will be in the same data with other option value and we will be sure that, default value will be the first. We could use Reactive Forms, and set default value programmatically via FormGroup